# Nodejs stops responding to promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, next.js, fetch-api

Say I have an api from which I need to collect some data.

```js
const fn = async () => {
  rootUrl = 'http://....'
  data = await(await fetch(rootUrl)).json()
  moreData = await Promise.all(data.map(async (elem) => 
    subData = await(await fetch(elem)).json()
    subSubData = await Promise.all(subData.map(async(Something)))
    Subdata.x= subSubData
    return subData
  ))
}
```

I use the function like

```
fn().then((data)=>{console.log('done')})
//or
await fn()
```

Sometimes I get the log, sometimes I dont. I assume because the promise hasn't been resolved yet. but when I don't get the log, it's surprising to me that none of the fetch throws an error(it should given that I wait 10 minutes or so)
My questions are:

1. am i limiting nodejs by any way?
2. is there a flag/settings i can use that lets nodejs have more resources?
3. is the issue related to me having too many promises and sometimes when one takes too long something else goes wrong?

More info on the question i asked earlier: [nodejs: making multiple http requests asynchronously pauses response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67783974/nodejs-making-multiple-http-requests-asynchronously-pauses-response)

Comment: Hi! welcome to stackoverflow! could you provide a working example? having `something`, `data`, or `subdata` doesn't help to understand what's going on.
Also, check how async/await works here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await

Comment: How large are `data` and `subData`? Of course you can overload your network with requests.

Comment: You haven't attached an error handler, so the promises might have settled already but you wouldn't know.

Comment: Did you mean to use `fn().then(something => console.log(something))`? `fn().then((console.log(something))` certainly doesn't work.

Comment: about 1000  for data and 1500 for subData

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely you are hitting any Nodejs limits on the number of outstanding promises. It is more likely that something is going wrong, a promise is being rejected, but you are not seeing the rejection.

If you invoke an async function as you describe:

```
fn().then(x => console.log(x))
```

then errors thrown by the called function as a result of a rejected promise will not be visible to you.

You may choose to invoke the async function using `await`, in which case a promise rejection will generate an error:

```
try {
  await fn(); // 
} catch(e) {
  // invoked if an error occurs
}
```

Or you could hook up your own promise rejection handler, something like:

```
fn()
  .then(x => console.log(x))
  .catch(e => console.error('an error occurred: ' + e.message));
```

This will allow you to see rejected promises.

Comment: well i use it with await, here i was just trying to explain the issue
i dont see any errors raised from anywhere. I thought about this issue of rejected promises so I did a test and nodejs shows me warnings when I dont handle a rejected promise.